# How "foo" === "foo" if strings are immutable?

Tags: javascript

Strings are immutable.
That means when I change a string - new string reference created instead.

If so how `"foo" === "foo"` give me `true` value?

The `===` compares by **reference** location in the memory and **not by the value**.

So, the first string should be new reference somewhere is the memory and the another `foo` should be save somewhere else in the memory.

How it is possible?

Comment: It doesn't compare "by reference". It compares *by type and value*.

Comment: "*The === compares by reference location in the memory and not by the value.*" that has ***never*** been the case. The comparisons are *always* done by value. [JavaScript is a pass-by-value language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language). The value of a string is its content, the value of *an object* is its reference.